# Ubuntu 12.04 lags very bad at my laptop

Tags: 12.04, updates, performance

So I recently decided to change from Windows XP to Ubuntu 12.04 on my crappy 1gb RAM & 1.6GHz laptop. The problem is that it lags A LOT. Like first 5 minutes I can use it fine but then it just starts to randomly freeze and process really slow. Right now I'm downloading updates for it in hopes to see if there's any update which will improve the performance of the Ubuntu, but I don't really think it will help.

Any suggestions on what I should do? Should I downgrade the version of Ubuntu even lower?

Comment: Try running `top` to see what programs are taking up the most resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to install old versions. And Ubuntu 12.04 is slower than 14.04 on old hardware in many cases.

But for your laptop I would suggest to install Lubuntu 14.04. It does not have enough RAM to work with Unity well.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? I'm still a noob in this kind of stuff, so can you explain please? Thanks. :)

Comment: It is similar to Ubuntu distribution with a lighter interface. It is made for weak hardware. Look at lubuntu.org

Comment: Xubuntu is also called a lightweight distribution, but it takes more resources than Lubuntu, I think. It looks much nicer and is more user-friendly in my opinion though...

Comment: But in this case xubuntu is too heavy IMHO. But may be considered as well.